# how can I replace all the whitespace chars with another character using input & output stream manipulators?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, manipulators

For example, I get an input from the user using `std::cin`:

`"This is a sample program"`

I want to replace every whitespace with another char and display it back like:

`"This\is\a\sample\program"`

Note: other characters can be anything. ex: `*` or `&` or `$`, etc.

I want to do this using stream manipulator. Is it possible?

Here is some sample code which I tried using std::getline but this is not the kind of code I'm expecting. I want to do this using any existing `i/o stream Manipulators` or my own manipulator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string spaceToStar(string text){
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(text);i++){
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            text[i] = '*';
    }
    return text;
}

int main () {
    string text, s;
    cout << "enter your line: " << endl;
    getline(cin, text);

    s = spaceToStar(text);

    cout << s << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do a homework assignment? Have you tried to do this? What happened? What does the code you wrote look like? What's going wrong with it?

Comment: Have you considered the special character appearing in the string? You might want/need to escape those then.

Comment: Do you want to create a new manipulator or do you want to use existing manipulators to achieve this?

Comment: [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) iterate over it check for a space and add your character.

Comment: What makes you think stream manipulators is the way to solve this? Why not simply use `std::replace_if()` instead? Use `std::iswspace()` or `std::isspace()` as the predicate

Comment: For manipulators, [`std::ios_base::iword`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) and [`std::ios_base::xalloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc) might help. but you probably want regular function.

Comment: @Omnifarious no, this is the type of question which was given in previous exam papers. I can able to do this 'stringstream' and  'if'  but I won't get any mark for my answer. I thought I can find an answer here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the suggestions. I'm new to c++ and also new to StackOverflow. so, apologies for not making my question clear and for bad formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the characters as they come through the stream buffer and create a manipulator for a streamlined syntax. Here's one way to do it, probably not the best implementation but it works.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

namespace xalloc {
  int from(){static int x=std::ios_base::xalloc();return x;}
  int to(){static int x=std::ios_base::xalloc();return x;}
}

template<class cT>
struct filterbuf : std::basic_streambuf<cT> {
  std::basic_streambuf<cT>* sbuf;
  std::ios_base& ios;
public:
  filterbuf(std::basic_ostream<cT>& str) : sbuf(str.rdbuf()), ios(str) {}
  int overflow(typename filterbuf::int_type c) {
      if (filterbuf::traits_type::eq_int_type(c, ios.iword(xalloc::from()))) {
          return this->sbuf->sputc(ios.iword(xalloc::to()));
      }
      return this->sbuf->sputc(c);
  }
  int sync() { return this->sbuf->pubsync(); }
};


template<class cT>
struct reinterpret { 
  cT from, to;
  template<class T>reinterpret(T f, T t) : from(f), to(t) {}
};

std::basic_ostream<cT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<cT>& os, reinterpret rt) {
  static auto nofree=[](std::streambuf*){};
  static std::unique_ptr<filterbuf<cT>, decltype(nofree)> buffer(
    new filterbuf<cT>(os),nofree
  );
  os.iword(xalloc::from()) = rt.from;
  os.iword(xalloc::to()) = rt.to;
  if (os.rdbuf() != buffer.get()) os.rdbuf(buffer.get());
  return os;
}

template<class T>
reinterpret(T, T) -> reinterpret<T>;


int main() {
  cout << reinterpret(' ', '\\') << "A B C D\n"; // A\B\C\D
  cout << reinterpret(' ', '*') << "A B C D\n"; // A*B*C*D
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for sharing the code... but, can you explain me the process of the code?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Every stream object uses an internal stream buffer class to store and process incoming characters. I defined a new streambuf class `filterbuf` that will process a certain character as another character and pass it through. The rest is boilerplate to allow us to have the syntax `cout << reinterpret(...)`. When you do `cout << reinterpret(...)`, it will change the internal stream buffer of `cout` to the our new user defined stream buffer `filterbuf` so that the next `<<` calls will work according to our needs.